# hdiutil fails to create APFS sparseimage: "no mountable file systems"

Tags: macos, catalina, filesystem, apfs, hdiutil

In macOS Catalina (10.15.7), I'd like to create and mount a *sparse*, writeable disk image that uses *APFS*. Specifically, this works if I create `Test.sparseimage` on my local disk. I'm just unable to create it on a NAS volume.

This works:

```
$ -> hdiutil create -attach -size 10m -fs APFS -type UDIF "Test.dmg"
..................................................................................................................................
/dev/disk7              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk7s1            Apple_APFS                      
/dev/disk8              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk8s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Volumes/untitled
created: /Volumes/Backups/Test.dmg
```

This works, too:

```
$ -> hdiutil create -attach -size 10m -fs HFS+ -type SPARSE "Test.sparseimage"
/dev/disk5              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk5s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/untitled
created: /Volumes/Backups/Test.sparseimage
```

This does not:

```
$ -> hdiutil create -attach -size 10m -fs APFS -type SPARSE "Test.sparseimage"
hdiutil: create failed - no mountable file systems
```

I've searched the man page, but can't find any clues about what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions on picking apart why the filesystem on my NAS behaves differently than Apple filesystem on my internal drive?

Comment: [This post](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/apfs-sparse-image-has-issues-when-created-on-moved-to-freenas-afp-share.74243/) suggests that it's a NAS issue. I'm investigating whether a SPARSEBUNDLE type will work for me instead...

Comment: If the NAS software doesn’t faithfully respond, that might be your smoking gun. Will be interesting if this is a bug from Apple or the NAS vendor or just not something afp or smb can do...